# How to move Wish List next to Qty input box in product detail page?

Tags: product, wishlist, qty, product-detail-page

I want to move ADD TO WISH LIST next to QTY Input box in product details page. Guide me how to achieve this

[image: Product-detail-page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the element next to the input box you have to create these files in your local theme:

app/design/frontend/Custom/default/Magento_Wishlist/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.wishlist" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist" name="add-to-wishlist" template="Magento_Wishlist::catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/design/frontend/Custom/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       min="0"
                       value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
                <span class="product-social-links">
                    <span clas="product-addto-links" data-role="add-to-links">
                        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('add-to-wishlist') ?>
                    </span>
                </span>

            </div>

        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button" disabled>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

The wishlist block will then appear next to the input field in the dom. You will have to use css for the finishing touch:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Just create **catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml** and use this code
> below:

```
...
   <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto.phtml"/>
   </referenceBlock>
...
```